# Using edittext to search listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have this Listview:

```
@Override
        public void onComplete(List<Profile> friends) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mSpinner.clearAnimation();
                }
                });

            // populate list
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Profile profile : friends) {
                //profile.getInstalled();
                values.add(profile.getName());
            }

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, final View view, final int i, long i2) {

                  Animation pushLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CallActivity.this, R.anim.jump_no_fade);
                  view.startAnimation(pushLeftIn);         

            }
            });

            ArrayAdapter<String> friendsListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_items2, values);
            friendsListAdapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
                    return lhs.compareTo(rhs);    
                }
            });

            mFriendsList.setAdapter(friendsListAdapter);

}
    };
```

I am trying to make the edittext filter the listview, this is what i have tried:

```
mySearchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // When user changed the Text
                    CallActivity.this.friendsListAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
                }
            });
```

I get no errors in the code but when i try to search in the edittext it doesn't work at all, what is the problem or how should i do instead?

Comment: Can you post your adapter class?

Answer (score 0):

Try do it in `afterTextChanged(Editable arg0)`.

And did you implement your `getFilter().filter(cs)`. Can you show implementation?